# How to force mdadm to stop RAID5 array?

Tags: linux, raid-5, mdadm

I have `/dev/md127` RAID5 array that consisted of four drives. I managed to hot remove them from the array and currently `/dev/md127` does not have any drives:

```
cat /proc/mdstat Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] md0 : active raid1 sdd1[0] sda1[1]
      304052032 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid0 sda5[1] sdd5[0]
      16770048 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

md127 : active raid5 super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/0] [____]

unused devices: <none>
```

and

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Sep  6 10:39:57 2012
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 8790402048 (8383.18 GiB 9001.37 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2930134016 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Fri Sep  7 17:19:47 2012
          State : clean, FAILED
 Active Devices : 0
Working Devices : 0
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       0        0        1      removed
       2       0        0        2      removed
       3       0        0        3      removed
```

I’ve tried to do `mdadm --stop /dev/md127` but:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md127
mdadm: Cannot get exclusive access to /dev/md127:Perhaps a running process, mounted filesystem or active volume group?
```

I made sure that it’s unmounted, `umount -l /dev/md127` and confirmed that it indeed is unmounted:

```
umount /dev/md127
umount: /dev/md127: not mounted
```

I’ve tried to zero superblock of each drive and I get (for each drive):

```
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sde1
mdadm: Unrecognised md component device - /dev/sde1
```

Here's output of `lsof | grep md127`:

```
lsof|grep md127
md127_rai  276       root  cwd       DIR                9,0          4096          2 /
md127_rai  276       root  rtd       DIR                9,0          4096          2 /
md127_rai  276       root  txt   unknown                                             /proc/276/exe
```

What else can I do? LVM is not even installed so it can't be a factor.

---

After much poking around I finally found what was preventing me from stoping the array. It was SAMBA process. After service smbd stop
I was able to stop the array. It’s strange though because although the array was mounted and shared via SAMBA at one point in time, when I tried to stop it it was already unmounted.

Comment: At this point, I think it's safe to use the `--force` option if you haven't tried it already. Also, what is process `276` on  your system? `[mdadm]` ?

Comment: It doesn't work, I get the same message: "mdadm: Cannot get exclusive access to /dev/md127:Perhaps a running process, mounted filesystem or active volume group?"

Comment: `sudo fuser -vm /dev/md127` might show what process has a handle on the array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I realize that this is an old question and the original poster believed that SAMBA was the issue, but I experienced the same exact problem and think that very likely the issue was not SAMBA (I actually don’t even have SAMBA), since it didn’t show up in the `lsof` output, but rather the user was already in the RAID mount-point directory when they switched to root or did a sudo.

In my case, the problem was that I started my root shell when my regular user was in a directory located on that mounted `/dev/md127` drive.

```
user1@comp1:/mnt/md127_content/something$ su -
root@comp1:~# umount /dev/md127
umount: /dev/md127: target is busy
```

Here is the output of `lsof` in my case:

```
root@comp1:root@comp1:~# lsof | grep /dev/md127
md127_rai  145            root  cwd       DIR      253,0     4096          2 /
md127_rai  145            root  rtd       DIR      253,0     4096          2 /
md127_rai  145            root  txt   unknown                                /proc/145/exe
```

Even though `lsof | grep md125`  didn’t show any processes except `[md127_raid1]`, I could not unmount `/dev/md127`. And while `umount -l /dev/md127` does hide `/dev/md127` from the output of `mount`, the drive is apparently still busy, and when `mdadm --stop /dev/md127` is attempted, the same error is shown:

```
mdadm: Cannot get exclusive access to /dev/md127:Perhaps a running process, mounted filesystem or active volume group?
```

**SOLUTION** is simple: check if there are any users logged in who are still in a directory on that drive. Especially, check if the root shell you are using was started when your regular user's current directory was on that drive. Switch to that users shell (maybe just `exit` your root shall), move somewhere else, and `umount` and `mdadm --stop` will work:

```
root@comp1:~# exit
user1@comp1:/mnt/md127_content/something$ cd /
user1@comp1:/$ su -
root@comp1:~# umount /dev/md127
root@comp1:~# mdadm --stop /dev/md127
mdadm: stopped /dev/md127
```

Comment: @sd1074 You might be on something, but I'm not sure if my issue was caused by spawning root shell from the path in question - I would have to stop the samba service, exit the root shell, change directory as regular user, start root shell again and only then stop the array. Which is possible, but not likely. I think that acceptable answer should show how to determine which process is blocking mdadm array from stopping. `lsof` clearly fails here for some reason.

Comment: @sd1074 If you have reproducible test case could you check if any of devices used as mdadm array component have open files reported by lsof? ( You need to compare numbers reported by `lsof` in DEVICE column against minor/major numbers of those devices).

Comment: @matt, I kept the log of my adventures with that raid. I added the output of `lsof` to my answer.

Comment: After two more years the issue hit me again and I can confirm now that it was the cause of lazily unmounted device (`umount -l /dev/md127`) AND bash process with current working directory still somewhere in mounted (now lazily unmounted) filesystem. To find which process exactly is responsible for the issue check this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/345422/59666

Comment: Same thing here too—I had an old session that was inside one of the drive's directories. In my case, I just rebooted the server and it was all good after that.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using LVM on top of mdadm, sometimes LVM will not delete the Device Mapper devices when deactivating the volume group. You can delete it manually.

1. Ensure there's nothing in the output of `sudo vgdisplay`.
2. Look in `/dev/mapper/`. Aside from the `control` file, there should be a Device Mapper device named after your volume group, e.g. `VolGroupArray-name`.
3. Run `sudo dmsetup remove VolGroupArray-name` (substituting `VolGroupArray-name` with the name of the Device Mapper device).
4. You should now be able to run `sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0` (or whatever the name of the `mdadm` device is).

Comment: This was the track that finally worked for me. Thanks @Vladimir

Comment: Good advice, different detail: When I looked in /dev/mapper, I was reminded by what I saw that /dev/mdX was a cryptsetup luksXXXX encrypted volume.  So I closed it with `cryptsetup luksClose mdX-crypt` and then I could stop the RAID array.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into similar issues but I didn't have the raid device mounted in any way. Stopping SAMBA didn't seem to help either. `lsof` showed nothing.

Everything just resulted in:

```
# mdadm --stop /dev/md2
mdadm: Cannot get exclusive access to /dev/md2:Perhaps a running process, mounted filesystem or active volume group?
```

What finally fixed it for me was remembering that this was a swap partition - so I just had to `swapoff /dev/md2` - this allowed me to `mdadm --stop /dev/md2` successfully.